# Da absurdidade de um limite mínimo para edição de uma pergunta

Tags: discussion

Estou a tentar editar [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/why-do-i-need-to-use-the-conjuntivo-or-subjuntivo-after-the-relative-pronoun), que tem um erro gramatical no exemplo dado. Com "você", conjuga-se na 3ª pessoa, penso eu.

No entanto, quando tento editar a pergunta, recebo uma mensagem de erro a dizer que preciso de alterar mais alguns caracteres para poder guardar a pergunta editada. Há alguma maneira de resolver, ou então contornar esta situação?

Comment: Já agora qual é o erro gramatical?

Comment: @JorgeB. «Você quer que eu te ligue?» Deveria ser «Tu queres que eu te ligue?» ou «Você quer que eu lhe ligue?»

Comment: Não, porque o "te" refere-se a ti, "você quer que eu lhe ligue" parece que te estas a referir a outra pessoa. Mas deixa ver o que os outros dizem.

Comment: @JorgeB, você quer que eu lhe ligue? A você?

Comment: fica melhor, não?

Comment: A mim não me soa nada bem mesmo assim...

Comment: @JorgeB. temos de chamar algum nativo de PT-BR para um tira-teimas

Comment: Que eu saiba, não tem nada de errado em "Você quer que eu te ligue", e pelo menos no Brasil é completamente normal ouvir frases assim.

Comment: Já agora, esqueci-me de dizer, mas não se devem corrigir citações/código, podem ser propositadas.

Comment: Old man, sobre pt-BR,  é comum o brasileiro misturar os pronomes da segunda e da terceira pessoa do singular na mesma frase.  É errado mas é comum.  Não é a norma culta e eu evito a mistura quando estou usando o vernáculo no meu trabalho diário.  Em casa eu já não me preocupo com isso.

Comment: [«Você quer que eu te ligue?» é gramatical?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3659/153)

Comment: @Centaurus dá aí uma ajuda à malta, nesta pergunta do Jorge B, por favor. ;)

Comment: Old man,  Eu não diria "você quer que eu lhe ligue?"   Soa estranho e como um cacófato.  Eu diria "tu queres que eu te ligue?"  ou "Você quer que eu ligue pra você?"

Answer (score 3):

Sim há um limite de caracteres que tem de ser alterados numa edição, penso que seja para proteger de edições só para ganhar 2 pontos de reputação. Podes sempre deixar um comentário ao autor, se ele não alterar, alguém com pontuação suficiente o fará.

[image]

Comment: A solução óbvia para esse problema seria contudo não atribuir os dois pontos de reputação nessas circunstâncias, não?

Comment: @Artefacto isso já é modo de funcionamento da rede, se quiseres podes propor isso, mas duvido que mudem. Está assim provavelmente para que as pessoas se habituem a editar publicações, para que todos possam ajudar na moderação do site.

Comment: @Artefacto além disso se não houvesse o limite de caracteres provavelmente apareceriam um sem número de edições a colocar pontos e virgulas nas publicações, em sites de grande dimensão não é com certeza fazível...

Comment: @Artefacto [Does Stack Overflow need to reward edits with +2 points?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252754/1817673)